# exc_bad_access (code= 2 address =0x0)

Tags: objective-c, c, exc-bad-access

I am new to this, trying to make an Minesweeper iphone app

i used a IBButton to Reset mine fields 
which is a 2 by 2 matrix of a struct

```
- (IBAction) Reset {
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x ++) {
       for (int y = 0 ; y < 10 ; y++ ) {
           f[x][y]->isOpen = NO;
           f[x][y]->display = 0; //Going to make a search function for finding Number of mines next to it
           int random = arc4random()%10;
           if (random < 2) {
               f[x][y]->isMine = YES;
           } else {
               f[x][y]->isMine = NO;
           }
        }
    }
```

so i get the the error at the very first line of my for loop
f[x][y]->....

what did i do wrong here?

/edit

This is how i declared my f

```
struct feild *f[10][10];
struct feild{
    bool isOpen;
    bool isMine;
    int display;
}
```

Comment: You didn't include a definition of `f`, so it's quite difficult to tell.

Comment: struct feild *f[10][10];
struct feild{
    bool isOpen;
    bool isMine;
    int display;
}

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you named it "feild" instead of "field"?

Comment: As declared, you have an array of pointers to `feild` structures.  Each of those 100 pointers needs to be initialized.  If that wasn't done, then that is likely the error.

Comment: was not paying attention to the spelling. thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allocated any space for f, so `f[x][y]` will just contain junk memory and then the `->isOpen = NO` access will blow up.

you need to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        f[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(struct feild));
    }
 }
```

before your code.